# Find the index of the Nth occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: string, perl

I've found `index` and `rindex` for finding the first or last occurrence of a character (or substring) in a string. I'm also aware that they have an `offset` that can be used to start at a certain index.

What I want to know is if there is a simple way to find the index of the Nth occurrence of a character or substring in a string. I'd prefer not to have to do it with a regex and would rather not to have to write a loop that just repeatedly calls `index` with an offset.

EDIT: I didn't state the restriction well. The reason I said "no loop" is I am looking for a built-in way to do it, which exists in many languages.

Comment: Why the arbitrary 'no looping'/'no regex' solutions? The simple solution *is* to use a loop. In fact, any reasonable solution would probably involve looping.

Comment: Your limitations are a little extreme and arbitrary. Why do you want to avoid regexes, and what's wrong with loops? I hope you realise that any solution must involve a loop, whether you can see it in your Perl code or not? There is no other way to count the occurrences of the character.

Comment: the 'no regex' restriction is largely because I don't understand perl very well, and regex is a large and complex thing to pick up while still trying to learn the language.  the 'no loop' restriction wasn't well stated.  the intent is I am wondering if there is a built-in way to do it, which there is in many languages.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this, you would need to write it yourself. Other languages that provide a way to do this are just hiding the loops from you.

Comment: The reason there is no built-in way to do this is because Perl has regular expressions, which are the correct tool for the job

Comment: @Borodin why are regex the "correct" tool?  Seems to me iteration is the fastest and simplest thing to do.  Regex are useful for a lot of things but arent the simplest tool in the world, especially since "Regular Expressions" aren't a standardized thing that's the same everywhere.

Comment: I'm curious, what language has a built-in feature to find the nth occurrence of a character or substring in a string?

Comment: What are you going to do with that index once you find it?  Are you planning to extract more data from the string from that point on?  This is exactly what regular expressions are for.

Comment: @ewok: I'm sorry if my meaning was unclear. My meaning was that because Perl has built-in regular expressions there is no need for a library call to find the Nth occurrence of a character. Regexes are the correct tool for the job *within Perl*. All of the various dialects of regular expressions are all certainly capable of this task. Do I detect a dislike of regex patterns from you?

Comment: @ewok: Please enlighten us, what are these many languages that provide a built-in way to find the Nth occurrence of a character within a string?

Comment: So I'll admit, apparently most languages that I thought had the ability built in don't. It may be my unfamiliarity with Perl that made it feel like this was more convoluted than it should be. And no, there's no specific dislike of regex, just a general lack of expertise. Regex is a powerful tool, but also a complex one, which means it goes beyond simply knowing a language to know how to use regex.

Comment: @ewok: `$s =~ /$s/` is not complex. Regular expressions are central to Perl and it is very difficult to do much useful with the language unless you learn at least the basics. Others have asked, what are you going to do with that index once you have found it? Presumably push it into something like `substr`? Regular expressions will combine all of that into a single operation.

Comment: I never said that each individual regular expression is complex itself, I said they are in general a complex tool. And I'm not trying to argue against them.  Regex are very useful for a lot of things.  But to me, it seems like finding the nth occurrence of a character in a string is something that shouldn't require regex. But at this point, we're getting into a nonconstructive philosophical discussion.

Answer (score 1):

One possible implementation:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use feature qw(say);

my $string    = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
my $substring = 'o';
my $n         = 4;

sub nth_index {
   my ($string, $substring, $n) = @_;

   my ($times, $index) = (0, 0);
   while ( $times < $n && $index != -1 ) {
      $index = index(
         $string, 
         $substring, 
         $times == 0 
            ? 0 
            : $index + length($substring),
      );
      $times++;
   }

   return $index; 
}

say nth_index($string, $substring, $n); # 42
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is much easier to maintain than a regex-based solution.

Comment: In what way? This is a pretty basic string matching algorithm

Comment: That is a hugely extended way of writing an `index` iteration. You have twice as many variables as necessary. Take a look at my own solution.

Comment: @Borodin I'm confused, I have two `$times` and `$index`. You also have two `$i` and `$len` (I should really pre-compute the length). Are the variables you are referring to the ones used to create the test case?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I have chosen to precompute the length of the substring to avoid calling `length` every time a match is found, but it isn't necessary. My point is that you have both `$n` (which is a copy of the parameter and so may be modified) as well as `$times` which is unnecessary. Largely because of the layout, I found your code quite difficult to grasp for a while.

Comment: Ok, I understand you point now. The only functional difference is the `$times` variable which was simply how I thought about it at the time. Counting down from `$n` is simpler.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I also think it's clearer to avoid the second condition in the `while` test and move it inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, there is no built-in for this. Here are a few ways, using `split`, `index`, and regex.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $str = "Xab_ab_ab_ab_";  # 'Xab_ab';  # test failed (3) matches
my $N = 3;  

foreach my $patt qw(a ab c) {      
  say "Find index of occurrence $N of |$patt| in: |$str|";
  say "index: ", ( ind_Nth_match_1($str, $patt, $N) // "no $N matches" ); #/
  say "split: ", ( ind_Nth_match_2($str, $patt, $N) // "no $N matches" ); #/
  say "regex: ", ( ind_Nth_match_3($str, $patt, $N) // "no $N matches" ); #/
}

sub ind_Nth_match_1 {
    my ($str, $patt, $N) = @_; 
    my ($pos, $cnt) = (0, 0); 
    while ($pos = index($str, $patt, $pos) + 1) {  # != 0
        return $pos-1  if ++$cnt == $N; 
    }
    return;
}

sub ind_Nth_match_2 {
    my ($str, $patt, $N) = @_; 
    my @toks = split /($patt)/, $str; 
    return if @toks < 2*$N;
    return length( join '', @toks[0..2*$N-1] ) - length($patt);
}

sub ind_Nth_match_3 {
    my ($str, $patt, $N) = @_; 
    my $cnt = 0;
    while ($str =~ m/$patt/g) {
        return $-[0]  if ++$cnt == $N; 
    }
}
```

This prints

```
Find index of occurrence 3 of |a| in: |Xab_ab_ab_ab_|
index: 7
split: 7
regex: 7
Find index of occurrence 3 of |ab| in: |Xab_ab_ab_ab_|
index: 7
split: 7
regex: 7
Find index of occurrence 3 of |c| in: |Xab_ab_ab_ab_|
index: no 3 matches
split: no 3 matches
regex: no 3 matches
```

Notes

- In [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) each delimiter is also returned in the output list, with capturing `/($patt)/`, for simpler `length` estimation. Thus we count `2*$N` (and then take `-1`).
- In regex the [@- array](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions) is used, `@LAST_MATCH_START`, for the position of the last successful match. Here the `/g` in scalar context in `while` makes it jump from a match to the next in repeated executions, and `$-[0]` gives the starting position of the last (previous) such match.
- The subs return `undef` if there are not required `$N` matches, including no matches at all.

Thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for comments on `return` from subs and on using `@-` instead of `@+`.

Comment: If `length($ch)` is always 1 then `$+[0] - 1` is the same as `$-[0]`. Also, `return 0` is inadvisable as an error return as it is a valid index if `$N` is 1

Comment: @Borodin  Thank you very much, corrected (along with other updates).

Comment: And shouldn't it be `return if @toks <= $N` or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples of how I would solve the problem

Subroutine `nth_index1` uses `index`, while `nth_index2` uses a regex. Both involve loops, as any solution must

I believe the regex solution is much more readable, while the `index` solution is probably a little faster. But they are both so quick that they are highly unlikely to cause a bottleneck, and readability is always paramount

```perl
use strict; 
use warnings 'all';

my $s    = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
my $ss   = 'o';

for my $n ( 1 .. 4 ) {
    printf "%d %d\n",
        nth_index1($s, $ss, $n),
        nth_index2($s, $ss, $n);
}


sub nth_index1 {
   my ($s, $ss, $n) = @_;

   my $i;
   my $len = length $ss;

   while ( $n-- ) {
      $i = index($s, $ss, $i ? $i + $len : 0 );
      return if $i < 0;
   }

   $i; 
}


sub nth_index2 {
   my ($s, $ss, $n) = @_;

   while ( $s =~ /$ss/g ) {
        return $-[0] unless --$n;
   }

   return;
}
```

#### output

```
12 12
17 17
26 26
41 41
```

Answer (score 0):

(This answer does not answer your question, but is here to help you down the road towards accepting a regex solution.)

The way you're asking for a numeric index of the position, it sounds like you're thinking of extracting data from the string once you have that number, in a way that C programmers might do it.

For example, say you had the string

```
my $str = "My daddy left home when I was three and he didn't leave much for ma and me";
```

and you wanted to extract all the data up to the first instance of the word "and".  Here's the way you could do it, which is sort of a C way to do it using Perl.

```
my $pos = find_index_of_first_occurrence( $str, 'and' );
# Note that find_index_of_first_occurrence() is a hypothetical function.
print substr( $str, 0, $pos );
# Prints "My daddy left home when I was three "
```

The way you'd do that in Perl with regexes is much simpler.

```
$str =~ /^(.*?)and/;
print $1;
```

With regexes, you're combining the searching for the string and the extraction of the data in one operation.  (Note that both code snippets ignore the case of not finding "and" at all, for the sake of simplicity)

I understand that you don't know regexes very well yet, and that regexes can be daunting at first, but you'll need to understand them as part of learning Perl if you're going to succeed with the language.